# How to update rows with Datatables keeping the sort and search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a page that loads data from a JSON file every seconds and puts the data in a table. I'm using the datatables plugin.

An overview of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
    function createTableBody(tdata) {
        var nRows = tdata.length;
        var tableHTML ="";
        for (i=0 ; i < nRows ; i++) {
        //create the HTML here
      };
        $('#QueuesTableBody').html(tableHTML);
    }

    function loadTableData() {
        $.ajax(
            {
          // parameters here
                success:function(data) {
                    createTableBody(data); //puts the data into the DOM
                } 
    })}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax(
            {
          // parameters here
                success:function(data) {
                    createTableBody(data); //puts the data into the DOM
                    var wtable = $('#QueuesTable').DataTable(
                        {
                        "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                        "paging": false
                        }
                    ) 
                } 
            }); 
        setInterval(function(){
            loadTableData();
        wtable.draw(false); // datatables method for redrawing the table
        }
        ,1000);
    })
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="QueuesTablePage">
    <table id="QueuesTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
      header row goes here
      </thead>
      <tbody id="QueuesTableBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The code works, in the sense that every second the data is loaded. Only that it loses the sort and search criteria.

What I want to achieve, though, is to maintain the sort and search criteria and the position in the window, meaning, I don't want that every second it should scroll all the way up. We are talking about a 100 rows.

(note paging is disabled).

Comment: Try adding `stateSave: true` initialization option and see if it helps, see [`stateSave`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option for more information.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com thanks for that info. I was not aware of it. Unfortunately it doesn't work (it should according to the documentation). I tried will all options of `draw()` and without it too. I will try again after rewriting my code to go row by row.